# Can Abingo Test run on haml?

Tags: haml

I am using Abingo to do ABtesting on my website. So it can generate different views as A and B. But all examples I find are using .erb, like this:

```
<% ab_test("signup_title", ["Sign up", "Registration", "Free Sign up"], :conversion => "signup") do |signup_title| %>   <% title "Free Sign up" %> <% end %>
```

Can I use ABingo to switch views in .haml? If so, what syntax should I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to HAML for your example is:

```
- ab_test("signup_title", ["Sign up", "Registration", "Free Sign up"], :conversion => "signup") do |signup_title|   
  - title "Free Sign up"
```

I assume you as following the [ABingo](http://railscasts.com/episodes/214-a-b-testing-with-a-bingo) Railscast.  Just be aware that these screencasts use the Nifty Layout generator and have a `title` method.